# WHERE not null for nested column SQL

Tags: sql

I have a select statement with a nested column called **Contents**

EDIT: this is the full statement, just need results back without **Contents** at null.

```
Playlists = (
            Select pl.Id as Id
            ,pl.Name as Name
            ,f.[Url] as PrimaryImageUrl
            ,up.Id as MemberId
            ,up.ProfessionalName
            ,up.AvatarUrl
            ,Contents = ( select c.Id as Id
                        ,c.Name as Name
                        ,c.ContentImageUrl as ImageUrl
                        ,c.Price as Price
                        ,c.BPM  as BPM
                        ,f.Id as 'File.Id'
                        ,f.Url as 'File.Name'
                        ,g.Id as 'Genre.Id'
                        ,g.Name as 'Genre.Name'
                        ,kt.Id as 'KeyType.Id'
                        ,kt.Name as 'KeyType.Name'
                        ,tt.Id as 'TrackType.Id'
                        ,tt.Name as 'TrackType.Name'
                        ,TotalCount = count(c.Id)Over()
                                from dbo.Content c
                            inner join dbo.PlayListContents pm on c.Id = pm.ContentId and pm.PlaylistId = pl.Id
                            inner join dbo.Files f on c.ContentFileId = f.Id
                            inner join dbo.Genres g on c.GenreTypeId = g.Id
                            inner join dbo.KeyType kt on c.KeyTypeId = kt.Id
                            inner join dbo.TrackType tt on tt.Id = c.TrackTypeId

            WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.Bpm 
            FROM @Bpm AS b 
            WHERE b.Bpm IS NOT NULL) 
            OR c.Bpm IN (SELECT * FROM @Bpm))
            
        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.Price 
            FROM @Price AS p
            WHERE p.Price IS NOT NULL) 
            OR c.Price <= ANY(SELECT * FROM @Price ))
            
        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT gt.GenreTypeId 
            FROM @GenreTypeId AS gt 
            WHERE gt.GenreTypeId IS NOT NULL) 
            OR g.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @GenreTypeId))

        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT kt.KeyTypeId 
            FROM @KeyTypeId AS kt
            WHERE kt.KeyTypeId IS NOT NULL) 
            OR kt.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @KeyTypeId))

        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT tt.TrackTypeId
            FROM @TrackTypeId AS tt
            WHERE tt.TrackTypeId IS NOT NULL) 
            OR tt.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @TrackTypeId))


                            for json path
            )
            
            from dbo.Playlist pl
            inner join dbo.UserProfiles up on pl.UserId = up.UserId
            inner join [dbo].[Files] as f ON pl.[PrimaryImageId] = f.[Id]
            where ( pl.Name LIKE '%' + @SearchInput + '%')
            
             order by newId()
            For Json path)
```

Right now, the result set will bring back objects with some having **Contents** at null.

I tried to write out a WHERE **Contents** IS NOT NULL but this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: can you post the whole query as right now it's just a select part? Select if the last. thing. which creates in query run, if you need exclude null for content, you need to put the whole thing in where and specify is not null, or do it differently, maybe have content as a separate table and join it with pl.Id

Comment: @Andrey added full statement

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)